# How to enable right click in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, mouseclick-event

I'm making a minesweeper clone, left click reveals the cell and right click is supposed to flag the cell.

I'm using the function `mouseClicked()` - this allows me to reveal on left click and also reveal on right click.

I tried using

```
if(mouseIsPressed) {
    if(mouseButton === LEFT) {
        reveal
    }
    if(mouseButton === RIGHT) {
        flag
    }
}
```

This registers once every frame that the button is held down. I just want a single right click. I imagine there is something simple that I'm missing, but I really can't find anything in the documentation or anyone asking about it online.

**TL;DR** - I just want to be able to right click in p5.js.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`mouseClicked()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseClicked) event only occurs once when the mouse button is pressed.

Set a state flag when the event occurs:

```js
var rightPressed = false;

function mouseClicked() {
    if(mouseButton === RIGHT) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
}
```

Reset the flag when the action which is triggered by the event was handled:

```js
function draw() {

    if (rightPressed) {
        rightPressed = false

        // do somthing
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `mouseClicked()` function and pass the `event`.

Then using `event.button` you can determine if it is a right click like so:

```
function mouseClicked(event){
  if(event.button === 2){ 
    // Right click 
  }
}
```